# How to get a cross-browser audio format from MediaRecorder API

Tags: javascript, audio, media, codec, mediarecorder

I am trying to use [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) in a way that it outputs a format that can be played back on all major browsers (Chrome-based, Firefox, Safari) **without server-side re-encoding**.

Here's what I have been scratching my head on:

- **What format/codec should I use** so that MediaRecorder outputs the most compatible output that can be natively played back by major browsers in a simple `<audio src=...>` tag?
- How can I configure **MediaRecorder to record with that format** and codec?

In the MediaRecorder[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) documentation, they configure the format this way:

```
      var blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
```

But it looks like tagging an already-recorded blob with a `audio/ogg` MIME
i.e. if I replace with audio/mpeg I don't actually get a mpeg-encoded output.